# Match string begins and ends with consonant

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

In order to matches any string that begins and ends with a consonant, while no consonants in between, I know that `r'^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][^b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]$'` works. But I would like to know, what is the problem with `r'^[^aeiou\s][aeiou]*[^aeiou\s]$'`? It seems that it doesn't work. And by the way, what are the difference between `'^ string $'` and `'\b string \b'` Thank you!

Comment: The middle part of both of them seems to also *only* allow vowels? Doesn't seem right. Also, can you provide examples of where your variant fails?

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question. No consonants in between.